# Веб сервис для аэропортов c#(ASP.NET MVC 5+WEB API 2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Я новичок в веб сервисе. Мне дали тестовую заданию Создать веб сервис для аэропортов. Нужно вводит первое: код исходного аэропорта, второе: код назначенного аэропорта. Должен вернуть маршрут этих аэропортов. Маршруты могут быть несколько. Не зная с чего начинать. Базу мне с нуля создавать или с интернета рабочие API взять. Можете мне подсказать в какую стороне мне копать))) Внизу описание тестового задание. Заранее спасибо.

***Тестовый задание***

The goal of the task is to develop a web service (ASP.NET Web API 5.2.x/ASP.NET Core 2.1+ based application) that provides API for searching a route from one airport to another. Please use the following service to get information about airports and available routes

The above service provides API your service should depend on. Swagger allows you to discover the available API.

The application you create should accept:

●   source airport code

●   destination airport code

and return a route between the provided airports. Please note, a route may consists of several hops.

The application should utilize minimum computation resources, apply appropriate errors handling logic and retry policies, effectively query the service to parallelize the route search and implement graceful shutdown (allows to stop the route search process). Furthermore, because of the instant load on the service(the application is proxied by nginx), it may just refuse connections, so you may need  to implement a sort of throttling logic to avoid overloading with significant number of http requests. Also, make sure your code is testable and the core of the search algorithm is covered by a reasonable number of unit tests.

Please note, routes you obtain are performed by airlines and they are not always functional, e.g. not active. You need to exclude such routes from the result.

Comment: Кроме того, что ваш вопрос очень общий, на который нельзя дать однозначный ответ, он еще и совсем непонятный.
что такое _маршрут аэропортов_ ? как вы представляете себе "взять готовые api" ?

Comment: лучше обратиться с этим вопросом на enSO, или же перевести текст вопроса полностью на русский язык

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам *следует копать* в сторону:

- изучения сервиса предоставления информации о аэропортах по коду
- придумать алгоритм общения с этим сервисом таким образом, чтобы вызывать его минимальное кол-во раз
- узнать как можно распараллеливать задачи на c#, а так же как грамотно их отменять
- как обрабатывать ошибки связанные с недоступностью сервиса и прочими возможными сетевыми проблемами
- разработать алгоритм выбора самого короткого маршрута, учитывая характеристики доступных направлений
- реализовать все это )))

Если в процессе выполнения **вашего** тестового задания у вас возникнут конкретные вопросы, подкрепленные вашими попытками (кодом), то возвращайтесь к нам - мы вам поможем конкретным ответом

Comment: спасибо, что уделили мне время для ответа. Я обязательно вернусь с конкретными вопросами)))