# Fluent Api и Web Api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, webapi, fluent-interface

Я новичок в Entity Framework и Fluent Api. Я создал несколько моделей, создал базу данных. Я не уверен, но я думаю,  что настроил Fluent Api. В базе пока данные остутсвуют. Проблема вот в чем. Когда я ввожу в браузер контроллер для Web Api появляется ошибка: например: ...../api/AirportAPI.

```
the 'objectcontent 1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type '**application/xml**
```

Когда я настроил в Global.asax, то ошибка не изменилось:

```
the 'objectcontent 1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json
```

Кстати, это тестовое задание [месяц назад я задавал вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/945066/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D1%8D%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-casp-net-mvc-5web-api-2?noredirect=1#comment1573136_945066)

Когда добавил данные в базу тоже ничего не поменялось. Можете помочь где я допустил ошибку.

Airport.cs

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Web;

            namespace WebServiceForAirport.Models
            {

                public class Airport
                {

                    public int ID { get; set; }

                    public string Country { get; set; }

                    public string City { get; set; }

                    public string NameAirport { get; set; }

                    public string Airline { get; set; }

                    public string CodeAirport { get; set; }

                    public bool Active { get; set; }

                    public virtual Information information { get; set; }

                    public virtual ICollection<Departure_Arrival> DepArrList { get; set; }

                    public virtual ICollection<PitStop> PitStopList { get; set; }

                    public Airport()
                    {
                        DepArrList = new List<Departure_Arrival>();
                        PitStopList = new List<PitStop>();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Departure-Arrival.cs

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Web;

            namespace WebServiceForAirport.Models
            {

                public class Departure_Arrival
                {

                    public int ID { get; set; }

                    public string Departure { get; set; }

                    public string Arrival { get; set; }

                    public int? AirID { get; set; }

                    public virtual Airport airport { get; set; }

                }
            }
```

Information.cs

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;

        namespace WebServiceForAirport.Models
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            public class Information
            {

                public int ID { get; set; }

                public string NumberFlight { get; set; }

                public string NumberBoard { get; set; }

                public virtual Airport airport { get; set; }
            }
        }
```

PitStop.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace WebServiceForAirport.Models
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public class PitStop
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }

            public string PitStopCity { get; set; }

            public DateTime PitStopTime { get; set; }

            public int? AirID { get; set; }

            public virtual Airport airport { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

AirportDBContext.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Data.Entity;


    namespace WebServiceForAirport.Models
    {

        public class AirDBContext:DbContext
        {

            public DbSet<Airport> Airports { get; set; }

            public DbSet<Departure_Arrival> Departires_Arrivals { get; set; }

            public DbSet<PitStop> PitStops { get; set; }

            public DbSet<Information> Informations { get; set; }


            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                //Primary Key for Airport
                modelBuilder.Entity<Airport>()
                    .HasKey(a => a.ID);

                //Primary Key for Departure-Arrival
                modelBuilder.Entity<Departure_Arrival>()
                    .HasKey(da => da.ID);

                //Primary Key for PitStop
                modelBuilder.Entity<PitStop>()
                    .HasKey(p => p.ID);

                //Primary Key for Information
                modelBuilder.Entity<Information>()
                    .HasKey(i => i.ID);


                //one-to-one Airport - Information
                modelBuilder.Entity<Airport>()
                    .HasRequired(a=>a.information)
                    .WithRequiredPrincipal(a=>a.airport);

                //one-to-many Airport - Departure-Arrival
                modelBuilder.Entity<Airport>()
                    .HasMany(a => a.DepArrList)
                    .WithRequired(da => da.airport);

                //one-to-many Airport - PitStop
                modelBuilder.Entity<Airport>()
                    .HasMany(a => a.PitStopList)
                    .WithRequired(pi => pi.airport);
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }
        }
    }
```

Global.asax.cs

```
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
                .ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        }
    }
```

Web.Config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AirDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\AirportDataBase.mdf';Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

AirportAPIController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebServiceForAirport.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WebServiceForAirport.Controllers
{

    public class AirportAPIController : ApiController
    {
        AirDBContext db;

        public AirportAPIController()
        {
            db = new AirDBContext();
        }
        public IEnumerable<Airport> GetAll()
        {
            return db.Airports;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну, прогресс по сравнению с предыдущим вопросом налицо, поздравляю. Мельком пробежался - каких-то чудовищных ошибок в моделях не увидел, но и особо не смотрел. Явно же видно, что у вас не с этим проблема, а с тем, что после чтения из базы (которое на этих запросах норм отрабатывает) у вас проблема с сериализацией ответа в xml.

Comment: Проверьте настройки, вы хотите получить JSON, а сервер вам отдает xml.

Comment: `return db.Airports.ToArray();`?

Comment: но вообще возвращать в контроллере типы предназначенные для работы с БД? Не надо так. Делайте для ответов из контроллера отдельные классы.

Comment: [связанный вопрос с enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23098191/312041)

Comment: tym32167, Надо создать репозиторий класс для ответа? Я установил Swagger UI. Swagger UI влияет на проект или на базу. Я вставляю комментария на xml в каждом коде. Я пробовал написать так и у меня появилось исключение return db.Airports.ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените конструктор AirportAPIController следующим образом:

```
    public AirportAPIController()
    {
        db = new AirDBContext();
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
```

А лучше сделайте отдельную модель для возвращаемых данных, как рекомендовал tym32167.
Дело в том, что когда вы получаете данные из Entity Framework, на самом деле вы получаете не свои оригинальные классы, а автоматически сгенерированные прокси. Эти прокси EF использует для отслеживания изменений в модели и реализации алгоритма Lazy Load и они очень плохо или совсем не сериализуются.
[image: Результат обращения к EF]
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; - выключит генерацию этих прокси.

Comment: Vyacheslav Benedichuk, спасибо за ответ. По моему проблему в таблицы бд. Наверно неправильно настроил вторичный ключ. Есть вопрос. Вы писали мне что я должен создать отдельный класс для возврата данных. Я создал обобщенный интерфейс, потом обобщенный класс. Дальше не знаю что делать. Можете помочь что мне делать?

Comment: С ключами у вас все нормально. Проблема именно в том, что EF подменяет ваши классы своими обертками, которые не сериализуются.

По поводу отдельных классов - имелось ввиду разделение классов, которые хранятся в БД и классов, которые возвращаются вашим API. Почитайте https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTO и https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/23.4.php
Хотя я сейчас подумал - у вас очень простая модель и преобразовывать ее не имеет смысла.

Comment: Vyacheslav Benedichuk, Спасибо, что уделили мне время. Теперь все понятно.